# Performing a single linkage like operation on python

Tags: python

I am stuck at a problem that might be easy, so all I'm asking for is ideas to get started:

In python, I have generated links between fileNames. Each fileName is associated to at least two numbers in a dictionary nameNumber `{fileName:[list of numbers]}` different fileNames can have some associated numbers in common. In order to see that, I created a dictionary numberName `{number:[list of associated fileNames]}`. What I want to do is some sort of single linkage: Regroup all the fileNames that have at least one number in common. This grouping has to be efficient as I have millions of fileNames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using graphs with [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/).

Each fileName would be a node of your graph (`G.add_node()`) and you could link the fileNames that have common numbers with edges. networkx should then enable you to find the cliques of you graph.